# How to create multiple rows from one json array field in postgresql

Tags: json, postgresql

How can I create multiple rows out of one json array field in postgresql.

```
create table coolant_consum(coolant_stock_kg jsonb, coolant_disposed_kg jsonb,coolant jsonb);
create table raw_json(data jsonb);

insert into raw_json (data) values
(
'[{"coolant_stock_kg":["3","7.4"], "coolant_disposed_kg": [
    "3",
    "7.4"
], "coolant" : ["R1","R2","R2"]}]
');

INSERT INTO coolant_consum(coolant_stock_kg,coolant_disposed_kg,coolant)
   select (j->>'coolant_stock_kg' ) ::jsonb,
          (j->>'coolant_disposed_kg' ) ::jsonb,
          (j->>'coolant' ) ::jsonb
   from raw_json cross join jsonb_array_elements(data) as j;

with lines as (
     SELECT coolant_stock_kg as arr, coolant_disposed_kg as brr,coolant as crr
     FROM coolant_consum
     )
select  arr->>0 as coolant_stock,  brr->>0 as coolant_disposed_kg, crr->>0 as coolant 
from lines
group by arr,brr,crr;
```

which gives me to following result

```
coolant_stock | coolant_disposed | coolant 
3             | 3                | R1
```

I would like to add the next row, and also it should not matter how many rows are following.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
select jsonb_array_elements(j->'coolant_stock_kg') AS coolant_stock
     , jsonb_array_elements(j->'coolant_disposed_kg') AS coolant_disposed
     , jsonb_array_elements(j->'coolant') AS coolant
 from coolant_consum AS j ;
```

see the [test result in dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/3OOFRcB2)